# How to find Thevenin voltage of two-port network from admittance matrix

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

The two-port network is powered by 10 mV voltage source and has admittance matrix: 
\$ Y = 
\left|
\begin{matrix}
y_{11} &  y_{12} \\
y_{21} &  y_{22}  
\end{matrix} \right|
=
\left|
\begin{matrix}
2 \cdot 10^{-3} &  -3 \cdot 10^{-5} \\
0.5 &  2 \cdot 10^{-4} 
\end{matrix} \right|
\$

From admittance matrix I know, that

\$ \left[
\begin{matrix}
i_1 \\
i_2 
\end{matrix} \right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
2 \cdot 10^{-3} &  -3 \cdot 10^{-5} \\
0.5 &  2 \cdot 10^{-4} 
\end{matrix} \right]
\times 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 
\end{matrix} \right]
\$

\$ i_1 = 2 \cdot 10^{-3} \cdot u_1 - 3\cdot 10^{-5}\cdot u_2 \\
 i_2 = 0.5 \cdot u_1 + 2\cdot 10^{-4}\cdot u_2\$

[image]

The task is to draw Thevenin's circuit for this and to compute its parameters. All I can imagine when I hear "Thevenin" is circuit like this:
[image]

I suppose, the parameters are \$U\$ and \$R_i\$. I would compute \$ R_i \$ as \$ \frac{1}{y_{11}} = \frac{10^3}{2} = 500 \space \Omega\$. Is that right? If not, how to compute that?

And I have no idea how to compute \$U\$. I know it is equal to voltage between \$2\$ and \$2'\$ nodes in this picture:
[image]

Any hint or explanation?

Comment: Can you post the complete circuit?

Comment: What do you mean? This is all I have. We have no other information.

Comment: sorry. I thought you had the diagram associated to the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the Thevenin voltage the port 2 has to be opened, thus the current is zero: \$ i_2=0 \$.
You get: \$ 0.5⋅u_1+2⋅10^{-4}⋅u_2=0 \to u_2= -2500⋅u_1 \to u_2=10mV*2500=25V\$.
To calculate the Thevenin resistance, do the same but with \$ u_2=0 \to i_2=0.5u_1 \to i_2=5mA\$.
Then, since the voltage drop is all on the Thevenin resistance
$$ R_{th}=\frac{u_2}{i_2} \to \frac{25}{5m}=5k\Omega$$
Notice it is the \$(y_{22})^{-1}\$.

Comment: Do you mean to put \$u_2 = 0\$ in the first equation with \$i_1\$ or in the second, as in your answer? Is \$R_i = \frac{u_1}{i_1}\$ or \$ \frac{u_1}{i_2} \$? I could understand the first case. If the second is right, why?

Comment: Added what I meant